# MySQL Export error using Replace

Tags: mysql, replace

```
    SELECT `template_id`, replace(template_code,"AT -","DE -") as 
template_code, `template_text`, `template_styles`, `template_type`, 
`template_subject`, `template_sender_name`, `template_sender_email`,
`added_at`, `modified_at`, `orig_template_code`, `orig_template_variables` 
FROM `core_email_template` WHERE template_code like "%AT - %"
```

This query it works and returns me some data that I want to export it. But when I do that from phpmyadmin I received this error:

```
      Error reading data: (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
 right syntax to use near 'FROM   WHERE 
(`core_email_template`.`template_id` = 27) OR (`core_email_template' at 
line 1)
```

What should I have to do to make this work ? thx

Comment: The error does not show the same query as in the working example. Check if you copy/paste correctly.

Comment: the query is working . as i said i returns me tha expected data. But I need to export it. I am using phpmyadmin. The export file content is the error that I posted